# Usando XML de uma ActionBar para criar um menu Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

Bom dia Pessoal, Minha primeira postagem aqui.

Estou com um projeto Android quase pronto, faltando apenas colocar os ícones no Menu Navigation Drawer.

Eu usei o seguinte tutorial para colocar os itens no menu.

https://thalesondev.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/utilizando-xml-para-construir-um-menu-navigation-drawer/

Meu código está da seguinte forma.

```
List<MenuItem> menuItems = createMenu();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MenuItem>(
                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    R.layout.drawer_item,
                    R.id.title3,
                    menuItems);

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

No tutorial ele diz o seguinte: Caso queiramos um icone em cada item da lista do menu, basta implementar um adapter com um layout que contenha uma imagem e usar a propriedade icon do próprio MenuItem para especificar a imagem do item do menu.

O layout acima já contem a imagem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icones"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_medi"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icones"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icones"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icones"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Line 1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Só que a imagem em questão fica se repetindo não e alterada da mesma forma que o texto é.

O menu é o seguinte :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_medi"
    android:title="@string/lblleitura"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_grafic_valores"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_graf"
    android:title="@string/lblGraficoValor"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_grafic_consumo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_graf"
    android:title="@string/lblGraficoConsumo"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_grafic_consumo_medio"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_graf"
    android:title="@string/lblGraficoMedio"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_noti"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_noti"
    android:title="Notícias"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

     <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sair"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sair"
    android:title="Sair"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Falta só esse detalhe para encerrar o projeto. Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: faz tempo que não olho android mas o fato de vc já setar uma :background e depois nos itens setar um :icon não da conflito? tente tirar o :background da imageView ou troca o :icon dos itens por :background

Comment: Bom dia Lucas, fiz a sua sugestão e infelizmente não funcionou. Retirando o background do imageView não aparece imagem alguma no listview. E tbm não tem a propriedade background para itens do menu.

Meu problema acredito que seja no Adapter pois não estou passando o campo em que os icones do menu teriam que ser colocados, mas se eu coloco lá o sistema já mostra erro. Eu teria que alterar o Adapter do MenuView.

Comment: http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter/ veja esse link talvez te ajude